# No Dialect mapping issue on SQL Server 2012

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa

I created a springboot app, using MSSQL 2012 as my database.
I have a storedproc that returns a list of departments

```
create procedure [dbo].[getDepartments]
as
begin
    select distinct department from ViewEmpInfo
end
```

`department` is a custom field `Name(varchar(100))`, not my doing, I just inherited from the previous developer.

On my repository

```
@Query(value = "EXEC [getDepartments]", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> getDepartments();
```

Calling it on my code:

```
List<String> genderStatsHeader = departmentRepository.getDepartments();
```

which results to an error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -9
```

I also tried replacing the return from `List<String>` to `List<Object>` but the same error occurs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you configured MSSQL as the SQL dialect? And hibernate supports stored procedures, you can use `call getDepartments`, so you don't need the nativeQuery flag..

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on the previous similar issues, I *Cast*ed the `department` with to `varchar`, it doesn't work with `nvarchar`.

I do hope it will help those who stumbles with this issue.